# CSS - Responsive Design

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am working on this wordpress style sheet.

Below code,
When I resize the screen using the mouse it kicks in and show the responsiveness.
But when I use the Chrome Dev tools and clicking each different device sizes it does not kick in. Also I have checked this via my mobile phone and its not showing the responsive design.

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
.specials{
    display: flex;
    //padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .content{
        width: 50%;
        padding: 30px;
        background-color: rgba($color: $primary, $alpha: 0.5);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        p{
            line-height: 30px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    .image{
        width: 50%;
        //padding: 30px;
        background-color: #000;
        img{
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your device resolution is <= 600px? Else only the styles outside the media queries will be applied. Same with the Chrome Dev Tools - did you make sure the devices you selected have width <= 600px?

Comment: Actually, @RenevanderLende, nesting is coming to CSS and [most browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=nesting) already support it. That aside, make sure you include the viewport meta tag on your page; something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`. That should help.

Comment: Cool, I've added an answer so this question can be properly closed. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your page is rendering things too small in the browser's responsive mode, then you probably forgot the viewport meta tag:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

Adding that will render your site at the proper size for mobile devices (including those emulated by the reponsive mode in desktop browsers).